# Number of paths of a certain type in a triangular array

Tags: combinatorics

Consider the $X_n$ set of finite integer sequences $(x_1, \ldots, x_{n})$ of length $n$ for which $x_1 = 0$ and $|x_k - x_{k+1}| = 1$ for each $k \in \{1, \cdots, n-1 \}$. Obviously $|X_n| = 2^{n-1}$. As an example $(0,1,2,1,2)$ and $(0,-1,0,1,2)$ are both in $X_5$, but $(0,1,3,1,2)$ is not. Given an element in some $X_n$, sometimes a permutation of the order of the terms will also be in the set. For example, (0,1,0,-1,0) and (0,-1,0,1,0) are both in $X_5$, but (0,1,2,3,4) has no valid permutations except itself. How can I count the number valid permutations for a given element of $X_n$?

The question might be viewed geometrically by considering the triangular array of depth $n$ which starts at $-k$ on row $k$ and increases by $2$ on each step from left to right. Here it is for $n=6$:

[image]

Then the question is, given a descending path in such a triangular array, how many other such paths pass through each integer the same number of times?

Comment: Small detail, but that triangle is for $n=6$. Also note that for a valid path that passes through the same integer three times, the path it follows between the first and second passing can be swapped with the path between the second and the third. More options are available if the path passes through that number more than three times. I think all allowed permutations are of that form.

Comment: I fixed the small detail. What about $(0,1,2,1,2,3)$ and $(0,1,2,3,2,1)$? Those two are allowed permutations but no integer appears three times.

Comment: You're right, and that's allowed because one part is at the end (add a $2$ to the end of both of them, and it'll be like the ones I had).